# Access element <pre> with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've this code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <p class="m-b-lg">...</p>
    <div class="text-right fz-sm">
        <a href="#" data-action="copy-link">Copy link</a>
    </div>
    <pre>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </pre>
</div>
```

How can I access to `<pre>` tag ?

What I've tried:

```
$('[data-action="copy-link"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var code = $(this).find('pre').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `.closest('.modal-body')` since your `pre` is not a child off `data-action="copy-link"`

Also, please note that `var code =` makes little sense to in front, at the current state.

```js
$('[data-action="copy-link"]').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).closest('.modal-body').find('pre').css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p class="m-b-lg">...</p>
    <div class="text-right fz-sm">
        <a href="#" data-action="copy-link">Copy link</a>
    </div>
    <pre>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working, try this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-action="copy-link"]').on('click', function(event) {
        var code = $('.modal-body pre').css('color', 'red');
    });
    })
</script>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p class="m-b-lg">...</p>
    <div class="text-right fz-sm">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-action="copy-link">Copy link</a>
    </div>
    <pre>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </pre>
</div>
```